# Capture keyboard inputs without a textbox

Tags: c#, string-parsing, magnetic-cards

I have a application that reads data from health cards and parse them for basic info like D.O.B., Health Card #, and names. Right now, I have a textbox that takes input from the card swiper and it works great, but I feel there could be a better approach for this.

I want to have a keyboard listener in the background of the application that captures input from the card swiper and parse the data without the need of a textbox. I figure I'll need a loop function in the Form1_Load that actively listens for keyboard inputs, prepare a buffer for the input, and then when a carriage return is detected, go ahead and parse the buffered data. When the parsing is done, clear the buffer.

My problem is I'm relatively new to C# and I don't know what I should use for listening to keyboard inputs without a textbox. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Here's my code in case if anyone's interested: http://pastebin.com/q6AkghvN

Just a note, I followed the credit card swipe guide from 
http://www.markhagan.me/Samples/CreditCardSwipeMagneticStripProcessing and modified it slightly for my usecase.

--- EDITED ---

Thanks Paul and everyone else for their help!

Here is my solution if anyone is interested:

```
private void frmMain_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "Reading Card...";
        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        if (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            buffer += e.KeyChar;
        }
        else
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Parsing Card...";
            if (buffer.Contains('^') && buffer.Contains(';') && buffer.Contains('='))
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] cardData = buffer.Split(';');
                    string[] caretData = cardData[0].Split('^');
                    string[] nameData = caretData[1].Split('/');
                    string[] equalData = cardData[1].Split('=');
                    tBoxHealthCardNumber.Text = equalData[0];
                    tBoxDateOfBirth.Text = FormatBirthday(equalData[1]);
                    tBoxFirstName.Text = TrimName(nameData[1]);
                    tBoxLastName.Text = TrimName(nameData[0]);
                    tBoxDateTimeScanned.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Error Reading Card";
            }

            buffer = "";
            lblStatus.Text = "Ready";
            lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if a keyup event on the form itself would detect the swipe but you could try it

Comment: I'm just looking at your code, at what point does the card reader actually send the data across?

Comment: @Shane.C from my understanding many card readers act as keyboards: they send the data across as if it had been typed on a keyboard. I believe bar code scanners tend to work this way too.

Comment: Ah okay! Didn't know that. I think Paul's answer may be the way to go then

Comment: If you want to put your answer up, it should be added as an answer, not an edit to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a key handler to the form you will not see the key presses when focus is on a control, e.g. a textbox. For the form to see the key presses even when there is a focused control, you must also enable the [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property.

You can then add a handler for `KeyDown`, `KeyPress` and/or `KeyUp` on the form as you desire to receive these events.

As you can read in the documentation to `KeyPreview`, if you set the `Handled` property to true, you can prevent the event from being subsequently sent to the focused control, i.e. you can hide certain key events from being seen by the focused control.

Comment: Maybe a better way would be to capture windows events for Keydown and Keyup so you can capture in and output even when you're application is not on top.

Comment: Thanks! I think that may be the answer I'm looking for.